# How do I enable python in my new GVIM 8.2 installation on windows 10?

Tags: python, vim

I installed the latest gvim from vim.org today. It is a 'loaded' package with many options, cfr infra (output of :version command)

I have python 2.7 installed, the python27.dll resides in c:\windows\system32. The python37.dll and pyhon39.dll are available in the 'c:\Program Files\python37' and 'c:\Program Files\python39' directories. These three directories with python dlls are on the system path.

Both Gvim and Vim output 0 on the `echo has('python')` and `echo has('python3')` commands.

Do I have to add anything in either .vimrc or .gvimrc to activate python?

Any suggestion and help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Guido

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Dec 15 2019 23:09:58)
MS-Windows 32-bit console version
Included patches: 1-12
Compiled by appveyor@APPVYR-WIN
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl                +eval               +multi_byte_ime/dyn -tag_old_static
+arabic             +ex_extra           +multi_lang         -tag_any_white
+autocmd            +extra_search       +mzscheme/dyn       +tcl/dyn
+autochdir          -farsi              -netbeans_intg      +termguicolors
+autoservername     +file_in_path       +num64              +terminal
-balloon_eval       +find_in_path       +packages           -termresponse
+balloon_eval_term  +float              +path_extra         +textobjects
-browse             +folding            +perl/dyn           +textprop
++builtin_terms     -footer             +persistent_undo    -tgetent
+byte_offset        +gettext/dyn        +popupwin           +timers
+channel            -hangul_input       -postscript         +title
+cindent            +iconv/dyn          +printer            -toolbar
+clientserver       +insert_expand      +profile            +user_commands
+clipboard          +job                +python/dyn         +vartabs
+cmdline_compl      +jumplist           +python3/dyn        +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist       +keymap             +quickfix           +virtualedit
+cmdline_info       +lambda             +reltime            +visual
+comments           +langmap            +rightleft          +visualextra
+conceal            +libcall            +ruby/dyn           +viminfo
+cryptv             +linebreak          +scrollbind         +vreplace
+cscope             +lispindent         +signs              +vtp
+cursorbind         +listcmds           +smartindent        +wildignore
+cursorshape        +localmap           +sound              +wildmenu
+dialog_con         +lua/dyn            +spell              +windows
+diff               +menu               +startuptime        +writebackup
+digraphs           +mksession          +statusline         -xfontset
-dnd                +modify_fname       -sun_workshop       -xim
-ebcdic             +mouse              +syntax             -xpm_w32
+emacs_tags         -mouseshape         +tag_binary         -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc"
 3rd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"
  2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME\defaults.vim"
Compilation: cl -c /W3 /nologo  -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_PATHDEF -DWIN32  -DFEAT_CSCOPE -DFEAT_TERMINAL -DFEAT_SOUND
-DFEAT_JOB_CHANNEL      -DWINVER=0x0501 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 /MP -DHAVE_STDINT_H /Ox /GL
-DNDEBUG /arch:IA32 /Zl /MT -DFEAT_MBYTE_IME -DDYNAMIC_IME -DDYNAMIC_ICONV -DDYNAMIC_GETTEXT
-DFEAT_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL_DLL=\"tcl86t.dll\" -DDYNAMIC_TCL_VER=\"8.6\" -DFEAT_LUA
-DDYNAMIC_LUA -DDYNAMIC_LUA_DLL=\"lua53.dll\" -DFEAT_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON
-DDYNAMIC_PYTHON_DLL=\"python27.dll\" -DFEAT_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3
-DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL=\"python37.dll\" -DFEAT_MZSCHEME -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Racket\include"
-DMZ_PRECISE_GC -DDYNAMIC_MZSCHEME -DDYNAMIC_MZSCH_DLL=\"libracket3m_a36fs8.dll\"
-DDYNAMIC_MZGC_DLL=\"libracket3m_a36fs8.dll\" -DFEAT_PERL -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS
-DDYNAMIC_PERL -DDYNAMIC_PERL_DLL=\"perl528.dll\" -DFEAT_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_VER=24
-DDYNAMIC_RUBY_DLL=\"msvcrt-ruby240.dll\" -DFEAT_HUGE /Fd.\ObjCULYHTRZi386/ /Zi
Linking: link  /nologo /opt:ref /LTCG:STATUS oldnames.lib kernel32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib
comdlg32.lib ole32.lib netapi32.lib uuid.lib /machine:i386   libcmt.lib  user32.lib  /nodefaultlib:lua53.lib
/STACK:8388608  /nodefaultlib:python27.lib /nodefaultlib:python37.lib   "C:\Tcl\lib\tclstub86.lib" winmm.lib
WSock32.lib /PDB:vim.pdb -debug
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual package of Vim on Windows ships a 32-bit binary, and a 32-bit binary will not work with 64-bit libraries (which is typically what I'd expect your Python installation will be.) You need both Vim and Python to match.

There are 64-bit versions of Vim packages available here: github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/releases

They're explicitly mentioned for those who want to add support for external languages such as Python.

---

Once you have a 64-bit Vim binary that matches your Python libraries, you need to have it correctly find the libraries in your system.

Try setting the `'pythonthreedll'` and `'pythonthreehome'` variables to point to the ones in your system.

It can be checked the python version required by checking `:version` output. In particular, the compilation flags shown at the bottom will show something like `-DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3_FLL=\"python37.dll\"`.

Therefore, it seems Vim was built with `python37.dll`, so let's try that version first:

```
set pythonthreedll=c:\\Program\ Files\\python37\\python37.dll
set pythonthreehome=c:\\Program\ Files\\python37
```

It's possible these are not exactly the paths in your system, or the values Vim wants for the settings... Please experiment with them and see if you find a combination that makes it work.

Note that you need to escape spaces with a backslash, and you need to use two backslashes as path separators. You shouldn't have spaces elsewhere in the line (for example, around the `=`.)

It's probably possible to do something similar for Python 2.7, but at this point Python 2 is basically deprecated, so I would rather spend time making Python 3 work rather than Python 2...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply and suggestion
I had removed python 3.9 and reinstalled 3.7 as one of the many tries to get the thing working. 
When reinstalling 3.7 the installer had the option 'Install for all users ' greyed out (beats me why).
So now I have in my .vimrc:

set pythonhome=C:\\Python27

set pythondll=c:\\Windows\\System32\\python27.dll

set pythonthreedll=C:\\Users\\guivho\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python37.dll

set pythonthreehome=C:\\Users\\guivho\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37

But neither python27.dll nor python37.dll could be loaded

Comment: Thanks! I just assumed that I had installed a 64-bit vo, never checked it :(
The 64-bit version locates python27 without my assistance, for python38 I had to set pythonthreedll and pythonthreehome.

Comment: Updated the answer to include information about 64-bit binaries.

Comment: Hi, @guivho I follow this guide, but my gvim still not work with python3. Can you give me some advice? I set `pythonthreedll` `pythonthreehome` like above, not set `pythondll`