# Vim Ctrl-] does not work, so how do I remap its functionality? (Windows 10)

Tags: vim

Today I installed a recent 64-bit Gvim:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Dec 13 2020 23:02:22)
MS-Windows 64-bit GUI version with OLE support
Included patches: 1-2143
Compiled by appveyor@APPVYR-WIN
...
```

I used to be a vimmer but switched to emacs and evil-mode a long time ago. I'm investigating whether I should return to vim, so ...

Strangely enough, the `Ctrl-]` key plays dead man in vim. It does not jump to the tag under the cursor, nothing happens when I hit that key, no reaction at all.

Jumping to a tag with `<C-LeftMouse>` does work.

The physical key does work. When I ask Emacs about this key, it replies:

```
C-] runs the command abort-recursive-edit (found in global-map), which
is an interactive built-in function in ‘C source code’.

It is bound to <menu-bar> <minibuf> <quit>, C-], C-}.
 
(abort-recursive-edit)

Abort the command that requested this recursive edit or minibuffer input.
```

I've also checked using the `key history tool` in an `autohotkey script`: both the `Ctrl` and the `]` are properly traced.

To verify whether I caused the problem in the small `.vimrc` and `.gvimrc` scripts that I created in the short time I've been trying vim, I ran both vim and gvim without my initialization files:

```
vim -u NONE -U NONE
gvim -u NONE -U NONE
```

Same problem, the key doesn't work.

Yesterday I accidentally installed the latest official 32-bit windows installer (which I removed today and replaced with this 64-bit version). I did hit this problem at the first run of the freshly installed gvim, but postponed looking into it until after my [python support problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65279044/how-do-i-enable-python-in-my-new-gvim-8-2-installation-on-windows-10) was duly fixed (thanks [filbranden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9447571/filbranden)).

So it occurs in both the 32- and 64-bit versions, go figure...

But this is really unfortunate, I don't want to have to grab for the mouse whenever I want to jump to one of the help-tags.

Of course, I would like to understand and fix this. But as long as there's no fix, I'd like to remap the functionality to another key, but I have no idea how to do that.

Any help either to fix the original problem, or in remapping the tag-jumping functionality would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Guido

Comment: `c-]` works for me in vim 80.  It's defined in `yourpath/vim\vim80/menu.vim`. Do you have that. I found coming from `*nix` that having a `_vimr` and `_gvimrc` on Windows conflicted. `.vimrc` doesn't seem to get picked up

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy enough to remap this particular combination like any other, to permanently set the binding add the following line to your vimrc:

```
nnoremap <C-]> :command-you-want<CR>
```

Typically, the command you are looking for is `:ta` which can be mapped like so:

```
nnoremap <leader>t :ta<CR>
```

You should be able to map it to whatever your Left Click is doing as well. If you check in `:help index` it should show you your current bindings. For me both `C-LeftMouse` and `C-]` are doing `:ta` I suspect your `C-]` isn't for some reason. You can try setting it to that manually as in the above example.

Personally I have a baked potato for a hippocampus and find I forget more  advanced bindings all the time so i keep `:help index` bound to F1.

Comment: Weird things are going on here: vim doesn't react on keystrokes that work in other programs. C-] doesn't do anything, regardless of what it is mapped to do. But my question was about  what command is executed by that key. I need to know how to map it e.g. to <leader>t

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clearer. The command :ta is mapped to that key typically. you can check your C-LeftMouse binding to confirm. I added an example to my answer. I would also double check if it is gvim only that is failing or if it is happening in the terminal vim as well.

Comment: That doesn't work: first time I issue :ta command on the first tag in the help.txt, either thru a mapping or directly from the ex prompt, I get an "E556: at top of tag stack" error.
I'm giving up:  I will stick with good old emacs / evil friends.
But thanks for your help and the time you've wasted on this.

Comment: But it works when you leftclick? Don't suppose you could tell me what your leftclick is bound to in :help index. Just for my own curiosity.

Comment: Ctrl-LeftClick does work. From help :index : CTRL-] :ta to ident under cursor